# convert cURL to coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, unirest

I am working on a project that involves RESTful Api and I need to upload an attachment to another server and that server will give me response if my upload is successful or not. PS: They require us to use `PUT` to upload the attachment.

I can use `cURL` to fulfill this process:

```
curl -s -u "username:password" -H "accept: application/json" -F "attachment=@file_path" -X PUT https://example.com/MailManagement/ws/v3/send/message/attachment
```

But when I write it by`cfhttp`, the response is `200 OK`, but their server would tell me

> "Problem while parsing request"

I use `cfhttpparam type="file"`,like below, it will say `Problem while parsing request`

```
<cffunction name="uploadAttachment" access="remote" description="Upload An Attachment">
    <cfhttp url = "https://example.com/MailManagement/ws/v3/send/message/attachment" method="put" result="httpResp" username="username" password="password">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data">
        <cfhttpparam type="file" file="C:\temp\1.txt" name="1.txt">
    </cfhttp>
    <cfset response_message = "#httpResp.tostring()#">
    <cfreturn response_message>
</cffunction>
```

I have insert the certificate for the url and it works for other api calls, but not for the upload file one.

That company gives us example codes written in `Unirest Java` fairly simple.I will put their code here, my code and their code should do the same thing.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.put("https://example.com/MailManagement/ws/v3/send/message/attachment")
              .header("accept", "application/json")
              .basicAuth("username", "password") // provide Direct address and password
              .field("attachment", new File("")) // provide file to upload
              .asJson();
JsonNode json = response.getBody(); // json response
```

Comment: Try setting `<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">` instead of `"multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: @Miguel-F I tried this, and it tells me `Multipart file upload required`, so I think I have to use `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Then keep the multipart header and try adding this as well `<cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept" value="application/json">`. That seems to be in both of your other examples.